# How can i pass the value (string) of a text box to a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

For the following program I'm suppose to create a class `WComplex` that perform operations on complex numbers. I did that and it is working just fine. In addition, I have to Create a Windows Forms Application of a simple calculator with 3 text boxes (`value1`,`value2`,`result`), 4 operation buttons (`+,-,*,/`). This Uses the `WComplex` class (by adding it as a new existing item).

The problem that I'm having with the code below, for instance I'm trying to pass the number in the first text box (value 1) to num1 (so i carry out operations) as the following: `WComplex num1 = new WComplex(textBox1.Text);` and I'm getting an error that `WComplex` takes two arguments (real,imaginary). But how can I read the value of form `(a+bi)` from the text box (v`alue 1`) and split it into 2 arguments or values? Also, what piece of code do I have to add to each specific button click that makes it carry the specified operation ? Ask for any clarification on the comments below.

**[update] - So I have figured out how to pass the two values using split and separator, see the button1_click (addition) below, but I'm still getting a debug error

```
Using WComplexClass;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Calculator : Form
    {

    public Calculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //text box (value 1)
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //text box (value 2)
    } 

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //text box (result)

    }

    private double button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //addition

         string t = textBox1.Text;
        string[] split = t.Split('+');

        double num1 = Double.Parse(split[0]);
        double num2 = Double.Parse(split[1]);

        string t2 = textBox1.Text;
        string[] split2 = t2.Split('+');

        double num3 = Double.Parse(split2[0]);
        double num4 = Double.Parse(split2[1]);

        WComplex num5 = new WComplex(num1,num2);
        WComplex num6 = new WComplex(num3,num4);

        WComplex sum = num5 + num6;
    } 

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //subtraction


    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //multiplication


    } 

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //division

    }

    private void Calculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: its a project, and I have on exam tomorrow that uses some of the concept of the Window Form Application (i'm kind of new to OOP and C#)

Comment: What is the error you get after your update? Edit it into the question.

Comment: Actually I just got it to work, but it is doing random operation. I have to figure that out

Comment: Good luck sounds like you have the hang of it :)

Comment: It is doing multiplication instead of addition

Comment: FIXED!!!! thanks man, finally works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question.  If the user enters something like 'a+bi' in the TextBox then you can use String.Split to split it on the "+".  You should also be validating and parsing the data so that you can pass `int` values to your constructor and not `string` values, which could be any text at all.

Comment: how would i use the string.split in this context ?
 WComplex num1 = new WComplex(textBox1.Text);
 WComplex num2 = new WComplex(textBox3.Text);

         WComplex sum = num1 + num2;

Comment: I worked around your concept and I got it to work, but what if the user enters the value in form of (a-bi), would I have to add another separator (-) ?